# Go + yaml.Unmarshal + maps - how to override

Tags: go, yaml

What's **the simplest** way merge two structs in Go **with maps** so, that existed keys are merged as well rather than overridden as it's done by default via Unmarshal?

Example code with better explanation:

https://play.golang.org/p/I4fWi-MPJaf

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "gopkg.in/yaml.v2"
)

type Application struct {
  Script string `yaml:"script"`
  Disabled bool `yaml:"disabled"`
  Options map[string]string `yaml:"options,omitempty"`
}

type Config struct {
  Host string `yaml:"host"`
  Port string `yaml:"port"`
  Applications map[string]Application `yaml:"applications,omitempty"`
}

const dataOriginal = 
`host: localhost
port: 8080
applications:
    app1:
        script: app1.sh
    app2:
        script: app2.sh
    app3:
        script: app3.sh
        options:
            option1: value1
            option2: value2
`

const dataOverride = 
`port: 9999
applications:
    app1:
        script: NEW-app1.sh
    app2:
        disabled: true
    app3:
        options:
            option2: NEW-value2
            option3: NEW-value3
`

const dataExpected = 
`host: localhost
port: 9999
applications:
    app1:
        script: NEW-app1.sh
    app2:
        script: app2.sh
        disabled: true
    app3:
        script: app3.sh
        options:
            option1: value1
            option2: NEW-value2
            option3: NEW-value3
`

func main() {

    var config Config
    if err := yaml.Unmarshal([]byte(dataOriginal), &config); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    if err := yaml.Unmarshal([]byte(dataOverride), &config); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("Actual:   %+v\n", config)
    
    var configExpected Config
    if err := yaml.Unmarshal([]byte(dataExpected), &configExpected); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("Expected: %+v\n", configExpected)
}
```

Outputs:

```
Actual:   {Host:localhost Port:9999 Applications:map[app1:{Script:NEW-app1.sh Disabled:false Options:map[]} app2:{Script: Disabled:true Options:map[]} app3:{Script: Disabled:false Options:map[option2:NEW-value2 option3:NEW-value3]}]}
Expected: {Host:localhost Port:9999 Applications:map[app1:{Script:NEW-app1.sh Disabled:false Options:map[]} app2:{Script:app2.sh Disabled:true Options:map[]} app3:{Script:app3.sh Disabled:false Options:map[option1:value1 option2:NEW-value2 option3:NEW-value3]}]}
```

I can merge them manually, not a hard thing to do. But in this case there is a need to update merging code along with config structure changes. Is there another way that is not specific for given config structure?

Comment: As "elegant" is a matter of opinion, it's pretty hard to answer this. There are some tools to facilitate some things like this. [mapstructure](https://github.com/mitchellh/mapstructure) comes to mind. But whether it's more "elegant" is entirely subjective. I tend to prefer custom code, over general code that uses reflection.

Comment: Let's replace the elegancy with an idea not to be coupled to the config structure. To keep the same "merge" code after the config structure was changed.

Comment: I want to explicitly second the mapstructure suggestion.  I'll stop short of saying elegant, but I've found it a very convenient way to turn maps into structs.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I decided to implement a merge solution, this is the result code: https://play.golang.org/p/VjrhGTAEGT8

Answer (score 2):

The most elegant and easy to pass this issue is to set the defaults on the yaml itself to something like:

```
const dataOverride = 
`
.app1: &app1
    script: app1.sh

.app2: &app2
    script: app2.sh


.app3: &app3
    script: app3.sh
    options:
        option1: value1
        option2: value2

.default-settings: &default-settings
    host: localhost
    port: 8080
    applications:
        app1:
            <<: *app1
        app2:
            <<: *app2
        app3:
            <<: *app3


<<: *default-settings
port: 9999
applications:
    app1:
        <<: *app1
        script: NEW-app1.sh
    app2:
        <<: *app2
        disabled: true
    app3:
        <<: *app3
        options:
            option2: NEW-value2
            option3: NEW-value3
`
```

The full example here https://play.golang.org/p/YNxbeprXCVL

If you really want to do it on the code level, you can explore the `UnmarshalYAML(unmarshal func(interface{}) error) error` method, but the solution for the Application map, will not be trivial.